# Ubuntu 11 Unity, how to open several instances of Nautilus with keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus, ubuntu-11.04

On the default installation of Ubuntu 11.04, if I press Windows key + 1, a Nautilus windows will open. If I press it again, it just brings the one Nautilus already opened to focus. I want to actually open a second instance. Is any key combination to achieve this?

Comment: Does Ctrl+N do the trick? (When you're in Nautilus, that is)

Comment: @slhck: Yeah it does, but I wanted to directly opening a new Nautilus from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows + Shift + 1** should fix it ;)